# Implementing a "fill-in-the-blank" component with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Basically, what I am trying to do is implementing a fill-in-the-blank system in Vue.js, but I'm having trouble coming up with a proper design to handle a certain functionality.

This is how far I've gotten so far: the Vue component takes a prop called sentence that follows the following format: "This is a [test] sentence for [demonstration] purposes".

The words that are supposed to show up as an empty input field are put into square brackets. This is what it is supposed to like:
 [image: screenshot]

I realized this with help of a computed property:

```html
computed: {
    sentence_parts: function () {
        return this.sentence.split(/\[([^\]]*)\]/)
    }
}
```

And with the following HTML code:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <span v-for="(part, index) in sentence_parts" v-bind:key="index">
                <span v-if="index % 2 == 0">{{part}}</span>
                <span v-else><input type="text" v-bind:aria-colindex="index"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Basically, I convert the string into an array in such a way that the sentence parts with even indices are put into a span, while the ones with uneven ones are replaced by a input tag.

**Now to my main question**: What would be the best way to implement a functionality that allows to compare the current input with the "should input" (i.e. the input in the sentence array).

The only idea I could come up with is making the input a model of the array field, but the problem is that I don't want to override the entries of the original array with the user input, but I want to save it into a "seperate variable" which I can then access from a function.

One thing that probably would work is creating a new array half the length of the original one, binding these to the corresponding fields and then calculating its place in the original array by multiplying it by 2 (for the comparison), but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

(For context, I am working on an application that allows users to test their grammar knowledge.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```js
const FillInTheBlanks = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <span v-for="(part, index) in sentenceParts" :key="index">
        <input
          v-if="part.input"
          v-model="part.guess"
          :aria-colindex="index"
          :class="{ correct: partIsCorrect(part) }"
        >
        <span v-else>{{ part.text }}</span>
      </span>
      <p v-if="allCorrect">All done!</p>
    </div>
  `,

  props: { sentence: String },
  
  data () {
    return {
      sentenceParts: []
    }
  },

  computed: {
    allCorrect () {
      return this.sentenceParts.every(this.partIsCorrect)
    }
  },

  methods: {
    partIsCorrect (part) {
      return !part.input || part.text === part.guess
    },
  
    reset () {
      const re = /(\[[^\]]*\])/

      // The filter removes empty strings
      const parts = this.sentence.split(re).filter(text => text)

      this.sentenceParts = parts.map(segment => {
        const isInput = re.test(segment)

        return {
          guess: '',
          input: isInput,
          text: isInput ? segment.slice(1, -1) : segment
        }
      })
    }
  },
  
  watch: {
    sentence: {
      immediate: true,
      handler: 'reset'
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    FillInTheBlanks
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      sentence: 'This is a [test] sentence for [demonstration] purposes'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.correct, p {
  background: #7c7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Input sentence: <input v-model="sentence" style="width: 400px">
  <br>
  <br>
  <fill-in-the-blanks :sentence="sentence"></fill-in-the-blanks>
</div>
```

The approach described in the question seemed perfectly legitimate, I just wanted to explore an alternative.

Initially I was going to have two data structures, a computed property (as in the question) and something in `data` to hold the user input. But I also wanted to clear the user input if the `sentence` prop changed. For that I needed to use `watch` to blank out the relevant property from `data`. Once I had the `watch` in place it just seemed easier to forgo the computed property altogether and put everything in one array in `data`.

Obviously using a `watch` instead of a computed property sets an alarm bell ringing. However:

1. The alternative still needed a `watch`.
2. Mutating the output of a computed property is definitely not a viable alternative.
3. Trying to keep two data structures in sync has its own health warning attached.

So I decided getting rid of the computed property was the least bad of the compromised options available. Depending on future requirements that's a decision that might need revisiting but it seems to keep complexity down for now.

I tried not to use the even/odd assumption for determining whether or not to use an `<input>`. Specifically I wanted to handle having an `<input>` at the start, though arguably that could have been done by putting a dummy space at the beginning instead. I also wanted it to handle consecutive inputs, though in practice that seems unlikely to be necessary as I'd imagine there'd always be at least a space between them.

Comment: This works great, thanks. :) What do I need to look for to understand the => parts in the reset part? This is the only part I don't quite get.

Comment: @Vallaris That's just an ES6 arrow function, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. There wasn't enough code in the question for me to know which version you preferred so I've used various bits of ES6 syntax.